# How to insert a known frequency in a sinusoid with different frequencies at specified time chunk using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, frequency

I have a sinusoidal  signal of 2000 msec length and varying frequency levels. I want to insert a known frequency of 10Hz at a known time chunk (600-800 msec for example). while keeping the rest of signal same. Any idea how can i do this using MATLAB? 
Here's how i generated the signal

```
%range of possibles frequencies
FrequenciesRandon = [8:0.5:13];
%number of randon frequencies ??
nf = 10;
delta=0.005; 
samples=200;
t=0:delta:delta*(samples-1);
ch2=[];

for j = 1 : nf

  f=randsample(FrequenciesRandon,1); % get the randon frequencie                         % Sampling Frequency
  signal = sin(2*pi*f*t)';        % Generate Sine Wave  
  ch2= [signal;ch2];    
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below code to yours to perform the example you proposed and plot it to check:

```
fInsert = 10;
signalInsert = sin(2*pi*fInsert*t);
timeStart = 600;
timeFinish = 799;
ch2(timeStart:timeFinish) = signalInsert;
plot(ch2)
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. Can you please mark my answer as useful? Regards.

Comment: I need a little more help with this code. Your help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: I have two sine waves with a time period of 2000msec. I want to correlate both signals for every 200msec interval and store the values in an array. That means for a period of 2000msec, i will get 10 values in my array. I am trying to do this using a for loop but i get only one value 10 times in the array. Can you please help me with this. Here's my code that gives me correlation value for a period of 2000msec.

Comment: Oh sorry can't upload code here. Let me tag you in another question. Your help means a lot to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807655/how-to-find-correlation-between-two-sine-waves-for-specific-intervals-and-save-t