# How to find correlation between two sine waves for specific intervals and save the value in an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, signal-processing, frequency, correlation

I have created two sine wave each with a different frequency. Time period for both waves is 2sec or 2000msecs. Code works well when i find correlation value for whole time period. Buth i want to get correlation values after every 200msec interval. That means i need an array that can store 10 correlation values for the whole 2000msecs. Here's the code how am i calculating correlation for time period of 2000msecs.

```
delta=0.005; %200 hz Fs 
samples=200;
t=0:delta:delta*(samples-1); % Time Samples 1second
ch1 = sin(2*pi*10*t)';
ch2 = sin(2*pi*20*t)';
cc=corr2{ch1,ch2};
figure; bar(cc)
```

Please help me how to create an array to commpute correlation value for every 200msec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly your `corr2{}` does but concerning your question this creates your 200ms steps:

related to your comment I added the part with N2 and N3 where N3_array now contains the sum of N3 over a period of 200 ms

```
clear all
delta=0.005; %200 hz Fs 
samples=200;
t=0:delta:delta*(samples-1); % Time Samples 1second
ch1 = sin(2*pi*10*t)';
ch2 = sin(2*pi*20*t)';
data=[ch1 ch2];

corr_period = 0.2; % in seconds (200 ms)
nsteps = corr_period/delta;
icorr = 1;
cc = zeros(ceil(samples/nsteps),1);
N3_array = zeros(ceil(samples/nsteps),2);
for it = 1:nsteps :samples
   %cc(icorr)=corr2{ch1(it:it+nsteps-1 ),ch2(it:it+nsteps-1 )};
   N2=angle(data(it:it+nsteps-1 ,:)); 
   N3=sum([N2(:,1) N2(:,2)],1);
   N3_array(icorr,:) = N3;
   t_plot(icorr) = mean(t(it:it+nsteps-1 ));
   icorr = icorr+1;
end
figure; plot(t_plot,N3_array)
legend('signal 1', 'signal 2')
```

you might need to adjust the graph

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. Here's a question..what does stepscorr indicate?

Comment: what if i want to do the same for the following case (see below)

Comment: 3N=sum(2N(1,:),2N(2,:));; %seperately add angles of both signals

Comment: I am using the same stretegy as you suggested above, but i get only one row for 2N. I am supposed to have 2 rows, one for ch1 and one for ch2.

Comment: @ Hafsah Ahmad: You cannot start a variable with a number so I switched 2N to N2. Also the way you sum the data will not work. If I understand you correctly this would be the way to proceed: `data=[ch1 ch2];  N2=angle(data); N3=sum([N2(:,1) N2(:,2)],2);`

Comment: Alright. This is right but how can i do this in a loop and store the N3 results in cc{} array you areated above? I want to link these two things. Means for every 200msec interval, i want N3 value to be stored in an array.

Comment: but N3 is not 1 value its 40 values..... I modified the example above and it does now the mean of N3 over 200 ms

Comment: Here's what i want to do.....i want to calculate the angles of ch1 and ch2 and then sum the angles of both signals for a 200 msec interval each. This means that i will get a sum of angles from both signals for first 200msec, then another sum for [200 400]msec and so on. And save these sums in an array.